# JavaScript RegExp group `**` with `+-*/`

Tags: javascript, regex

Now I'd like to match an expression string with JavaScript RegExp.

Example:
`'1**2*3+4'` -> `['1', '**', '2', '*', '3', '+', '4']`,
instead of `['1', '*', '*', '2', '*', '3', '+', '4']`

How Can I do it base on the following RegExp?

`'1**2*3+4'.match(/[*\/+-]|\d+/g)`

Also, I wanna place `(\*\*)` in Brackets together with `+-*/` but not like:
`/\*\*|[*\/+-]|\d+/g`

Comment: Repeat the first character class `[*\/+-]+|\d+` https://regex101.com/r/HnwO7I/1 or repeat the asterix separately `[\/+-]|\*+|\d+` https://regex101.com/r/vm70vN/1

Comment: Did any of the answers work out?

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the asterix separately from the character class to match one or more `*` as a whole match without mixing with `/` `+` and `-`

```
[\/+-]|\*+|\d+
```

- `[\/+-]` Match one of `/` `+` `-`
- `|` Or
- `\*+` Match one or more `*`
- `|` Or
- `\d+` Match 1 or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJVdrD/1)

```js
let s = '1**2*3+4';
console.log(s.match(/[\/+-]|\*+|\d+/g));
```

If you also want to match `+-` as a single match, you can repeat the character class  by itself.

```
[*\/+-]+|\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IUSgzK/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a double-character inside the square brackets (square brackets are just shorthand for single character OR), so you have to use the option you provided. This is the correct way to do this:

```regex
/\*\*|[*\/+-]|\d+/g
```

The reason this matches the `**` is that the `\*\*` is *before* the single `*` in the brackets.

On the other hand, if you mean that you want to match any of your repeating special characters as single groups (ie, `//` should also be `//` and not `/`,`/`), then you should expand the brackets out into full `|` syntax and add `+` (one or more of the preceding character) to each one:

```
/\*+|\/+|\++|\-+|\d+/g
```

This says "match all instances of at least one `*`, at least one `/`, at least one `+`, at least one `-`, or at least one digit."

If you want to only match *up to* 2 of each, you have to replace each `+` with `{1,2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom quantifier:

```
'1**2*3+4'.match(/[*\/+-]{1,2}|\d+/g)
```